# XPages SSJS get all users under a role and put into combobox?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I did the following code in my combobox values but it's empty although I did put some user into the ACL with the roles 'Reviewer':

```
var arr=new Array();
var acl:NotesACL=database.getACL();
var acle:NotesACLEntry=acl.getFirstEntry();
while(acle.getRoles().contains('[Reviewer]')){
    arr.push(acle.getName());
    acle=acl.getNextEntry(acle);
}
return arr;
```

My database is on a server. I'm using 8.5.3 FP3 UP1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you listed will exit the while loop as soon as it encounters an entry that does not have the specified role enabled. So if the first entry does not have the role, it would never enter the loop. I suggest three changes to the code:

1. First, never use `new Array()`... use `[ ]` instead. In addition to simply being less characters to type each time, in browsers, [the array literal performs better](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-literal/9), so it's good to be in this habit even in SSJS, where the performance difference is less likely to be noticeable. Similarly, while this doesn't pertain to your specific example, never use `new Object()`; just use `{ }`.
2. Instead of checking the role in your while condition, compare `acle` to `null`, and check the role *inside* the loop. This will ensure that all entries with the specified role are returned, regardless of their order in the ACL.
3. In order to [avoid leaking C++ handles](http://nathantfreeman.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/recycle-and-the-retail-experience/), you'll need to recycle each entry before checking the next one.

Put the three changes together, and the revised code looks like this:

```
var arr = [ ];
var acl:NotesACL=database.getACL();
var acle:NotesACLEntry=acl.getFirstEntry();
var nextEntry:NotesACLEntry = null;
while(acle != null){
    if (acle.getRoles().contains('[Reviewer]')) {
        arr.push(acle.getName());
    }
    nextEntry = acl.getNextEntry(acle);
    acle.recycle();
    acle = nextEntry;
}
return arr;
```

Comment: I haven't personally benchmarked this, but it would surprise me if there was any difference between the two. All SSJS becomes Java at runtime, so either syntax should result in an instance of com.ibm.jscript.std.ArrayObject. Once that instance is created, any operations against it should (in theory) perform identically regardless of how it was created. If there's any difference at all, it's likely in the initial parsing: SSJS becomes Java when the entire value / method binding is parsed into an AST. The array literal may require slightly less processing during this step.